# Angular 9 - Cannot find control with path: 'xxx -> 2 -> xxx'

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, dynamic-arrays

I have used reactive forms in Angular project along with PrimeNg p-multi-select. The multi-select drop-downs are dynamic that they are generating by repeating a list. When I use reactive forms with form-group and form-array, it allows me to fetch the 0th item but not the rest. Please advise on potential fix.

Following errors can be seen in the console.

- Cannot find control with path: 'attributeOptionForm -> 3'
- Cannot find control with path: 'attributeOptionForm -> 3 -> options'

Component.ts

```
  export class VisualisationComponent implements OnInit {
    sidebarFilterForm: FormGroup;
    attributeForm: FormArray;
    attributeOptionForm: FormArray;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidebarFilterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      attributeOptionForm: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
    });
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      options: '',
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.attributeForm = this.sidebarFilterForm.get('options') as FormArray;
    this.attributeForm.push(this.createItem());
  }
```

Component.html

```
<div formArrayName="attributeOptionForm">
  <div
    class="ce-survey-filter-item mt-2"
    *ngFor="
        let item of attribute;
        let i = index;
        let opt of sidebarFilterForm.get('attributeOptionForm').controls">
    <label for="" class="ce-filter-results-text mb-0">{{ item.attributeName}}</label>
    <div class="ce-survey-filter-item">
      <div class="prm-multi-select" [formGroupName]="i">
        <p-multiSelect
          [options]="attributeOptions[i]"
          [optionLabel]="'Attribute Options'"
          [dropdownIcon]="'bx bxs-chevron-down'"
          defaultLabel="Attribute Options"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedAttributeOptions[i]"
          formControlName="options"
        ></p-multiSelect>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following output is the one I get once I console log the output
[Output of the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8uGM.png)

I found similar questions related to this. But none were helpful.

Comment: is it the whole component.html in the question? or it is missing the most root div?

Comment: @Andrei Since the file is too long, I have put the exact div only.

Comment: does it have [formGroup]="sidebarFilterForm" somewhere in the tree?

Comment: @Andrei Yes it has. Please find the following line.
<form [formGroup]="sidebarFilterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">